Simulating data from a Probability Distribution when we don't know the Probability Distribution?
Suppose we have an exponential distribution:
$$f(x; \lambda) = \begin{cases} 
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \text{for } x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{for } x < 0
\end{cases}$$
From here, we can find out the first $k$ theoretical moments:
$$\mu_1 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$
$$\mu_2 = \frac{2}{\lambda^2}$$
$$\mu_3 = \frac{6}{\lambda^3}$$
$$\mu_4 = \frac{24}{\lambda^4}$$
$$\mu_k = \frac{k!}{\lambda^k}$$
We can also relate these to the first $k$ empirical moments:
$$\hat{\mu}_1 = \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
$$\hat{\mu}_2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$$
$$\hat{\mu}_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k$$
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$
$$\text{skewness} = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^3}{(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$\text{kurtosis} = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^4}{(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2)^2}$$
This is the question: Suppose we are given a fixed value of $\lambda$, and the closed form expressions for the first $k$ moments of some random variable $x$ (i.e. provided with $\mu_1, mu_2, ... mu_k$), but we are not told the pdf of $x$. In this case, is it possible to:

Question 1: Reconstruct what might be the pdf of the random variable $x$?
Question 2: Simulate data from $x$?

I am not sure about question 1, but for question 2, I think it might be possible to simulate a lot of data from a uniform distribution, randomly select small samples from the uniform distribution, calculate the values of $\mu_1, mu_2, ... mu_k$ from a small sample and see if its approximately equal to the to theoretical value? Perhaps we can use metaheuristics/evolutionary algorithms to try and to do this?
Is there a better way to do this? Or is this simply impossible?
Cheers

Supporting formulas:
Here is the formula for the nth empirical moment:
$$\hat{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^n$$
Where:

$\hat{\mu}_n$ is the nth empirical moment
$N$ is the total number of observations in the sample
$X_i$ represents the ith observation in the sample
$n$ is the order of the moment (a positive integer)

Here is the formula for finding out the nth moment if we know the probability distribution function:
$$\mu_k = E[X^k] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^k f(x) dx$$
For the exponential distribution, this becomes:
$$\mu_k = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^k \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$$
Here is the formula for moving between an MGF and PDF:
$$M_X(t) = \mathcal{L}\{f_X(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx} f_X(x) dx$$
Where:

$M_X(t)$ is the Moment Generating Function
$f_X(x)$ is the Probability Density Function
$\mathcal{L}\{\}$ denotes the Laplace transform


Here is an R simulation that analyzes the following situation:

We have a exponential distribution with $\lambda$ = 23, yet we are not told this
We generate 10,000 points from a uniform distribution
From these 10,000 points, we take a sample of 30 points and calculate the empirical first 4 moments ... then calculate the average distance from the first 4 theoretical moments and the first 4 empirical moments
Repeat this simulation multiple times and plot the results

Below are the results:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

lambda <- 23
n_simulations <- 500
sample_size <- 30
n_uniform <- 10000  

theoretical_moments <- sapply(1:4, function(k) factorial(k) / lambda^k)

calculate_moments <- function(x) {
    c(
        mean(x),
        mean(x^2),
        mean(x^3),
        mean(x^4)
    )
}

set.seed(123)
uniform_data <- runif(n_uniform, 0, 1)

results <- replicate(n_simulations, {
    sample_data <- sample(uniform_data, size = sample_size, replace = TRUE)
    
    empirical_moments <- calculate_moments(sample_data)
    
    diff <- empirical_moments - theoretical_moments
    
    mean(abs(diff))
})

avg_distance_df <- data.frame(
    Simulation = 1:n_simulations,
    AvgDistance = results
)

overall_mean_distance <- mean(results)

lowest_point <- avg_distance_df %>%
    arrange(AvgDistance) %>%
    slice(1)

p <- ggplot(avg_distance_df, aes(x = Simulation, y = AvgDistance)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_point(color = "blue", size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = lowest_point, aes(x = Simulation, y = AvgDistance), 
               color = "red", size = 3) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = lowest_point$AvgDistance, 
               linetype = "dotted", color = "red") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        title = paste("Average Distance from Exponential Moments (λ =", lambda, ")\n",
                      "Using Uniform Data, Sample Size =", sample_size),
        subtitle = paste("Theoretical Moments:", 
                         paste(round(theoretical_moments, 4), collapse = ", ")),
        x = "Simulation Number",
        y = "Average Absolute Distance"
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    ) 

print(p)


The sample corresponding to the red dot has empirical moments closest to the theoretical moments.

Here is another simulation which takes random samples from a uniform distribution, calculates the EDFs, plots them - and compares them to the EDF of an exponential. Ideally, we would try to take the samples closest to the red line as the approximate samples (note: this is only relevant if we know the true distribution):
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

lambda <- 23
n_simulations <- 700
sample_size <- 30

# Function to create EDF
create_edf <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    x_sorted <- sort(x)
    data.frame(
        x = c(0, x_sorted, 1), 
        y = c(0, seq(1/n, 1, 1/n), 1)
    )
}

set.seed(123)
all_edfs <- replicate(n_simulations, {
    sample <- runif(sample_size)
    create_edf(sample)
}, simplify = FALSE)

plot_data <- bind_rows(all_edfs, .id = "simulation")

x_range <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000)
theoretical_exp <- data.frame(x = x_range, y = 1 - exp(-lambda * x_range))

p <- ggplot() +
    geom_step(data = plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = simulation), 
              color = "black", alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_line(data = theoretical_exp, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", size = 1) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        title = paste("Uniform EDFs vs Exponential CDF (λ =", lambda, ")"),
        subtitle = paste("Sample Size =", sample_size, ", Number of Simulations =", n_simulations),
        x = "Value",
        y = "Cumulative Probability"
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    ) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))

print(p)



The space of distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ having finite moment of any order is still infinite-dimensional. This means that you cannot uniquely identify a distribution only from its first $k$ moments. (In fact, even knowing the moment of every order is not sufficient in general! You might also find this article about moment problem interesting.) This means that essentially you have to impose further conditions, either explicit (such as considering a parametric model) or implicit, to your problem in order to have better chance for uniqueness.

thank you for this article!

@SangchulLee Hi Sangchul my friend!  How are you doing?  I hope that all is going well for you. Just FYI ... I clicked on the link you provided in your comment and the Wikipedia article is effectively devoid of content. There is a message that states "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name. Please search for Moment problems in Wikipedia to check for alternative titles or spellings."

@ Mark: I searched the url on google and found the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem

@MarkViola Hi Mark, I'm doing well, hope you're too! :) I realized that somehow I ended up adding an extra 's' to the url, causing the link to break down. Sorry for the confusion. Gladly, OP figured out the correct link to the page by themselves.

does the first simulation approach i described make sense?

Did you find solutions to your problems? Do you still need to have some help?
